# How can I add thread and class name to Java Util Logging API via configuration files?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

If I want to display thread, class, and method names in Java Util Logging API, can this be configured in the logging.properties file, or do I need to modify the code?

Comment: You have to write your own [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) implementation. The `SimpleFormatter` takes a configurable format string but does not make the thread available. The underlying `Formatter.formatMessage()` does, because it receives a `LogRecord` containing everything that is available.

Comment: @user207421 so are you saying this cannot be controlled via a config file, you need to create a formatted?

Comment: That's what I said.

Answer (score 2):

By "display thread" do you mean thread name or thread id?  The more standard formatters are only going to include what the log record provides which is the thread id and not the name.  As @user207421 said, the SimpleFormatter doesn't include all LogRecord properties.

The [java.util.logging.XMLFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/XMLFormatter.html) includes thread id, source class, and method names.  That can work for file output which and later be styled to make it look nice.

If you have dependencies on Angus-Mail or JavaMail they have the [com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.angus/jakarta.mail/latest/jakarta.mail/com/sun/mail/util/logging/CompactFormatter.html) which can output the thread id and source (simpleclassname.methodname).  However, this formatter will hide some additional information that the SimpleFormatter provides.

You may have to find a 3rd party formatter or write your own formatter to display what you need.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can't get thread name, but you can get a log via configuration as follows:
The formatting can be customized by specifying the format string in the java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property. The given LogRecord will be formatted as if by calling:

```
String.format(format, date, source, logger, level, message, thrown);
```

where the arguments are:

1. format - the java.util.Formatter format string specified in the
   java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property or the default
   format.
2. date - a Date object representing event time of the log
   record.
3. source - a string representing the caller, if available;
   otherwise, the logger's name.
4. logger - the logger's name.
5. level - the log level.
6. message - the formatted log message returned from the Formatter.formatMessage(LogRecord) method. It uses java.text formatting and does not use the java.util.Formatter format argument.
7. thrown - a string representing the throwable associated with the log record and its backtrace beginning with a newline character, if any; otherwise, an empty string.
   For more details see
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)